# Stop or remove a running tween

Tags: javascript, tween, createjs

I found a function that remove all running tweens from all targets, and work fine:

```
    /** 
 * Removes all registered tweens for all targets.
 * @method removeTweens
 * @static
 **/
createjs.Tween.removeAllTweens = function() {
    var tweens = createjs.Tween._tweens;
    for (var i=tweens.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        tweens[i]._paused = true;
        tweens.splice(i,1);
    }
};
```

but i want a function that remove one tween, i tried many ways but not solve my problem. Anyone help me please... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TweenJS GitHub repository just received an update that includes a `removeTween` method.